# How to tell if text in a UITextField is bold or italicized?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that allows users to edit whether the text inside is Bold or Italicized using the `allowsEditingTextAttirbutes` flag.

I'm wondering how to get the text from that UITextField, along with the information about what state the text is in. So if someone submits:

My *name* is **Jonas**

I would like to be able to tell that the word "Jonas" is bolded and that "name" is italicized

Thank you!